# Excel: How to make list of folders in folder that automatically update

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up an excel sheet with a list of folders in a main folder (not including sub folders within the folders). I've succeeded in running a VBA to create the list and then I have used the list to add on the different information needed for each folder (see image of visual setup). 
But I would like to be able to update the list, so whenever new folders are added to the main folder it will appear on the list in the sheet. 
Is it possible to update the list to the format I have created either by macro, or button or automatically ?

[image: Visual setup of sheet using vba code for data in coloumn A]

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListFoldersInDirectory()


Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolders As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim strDirectory As String
Dim arrFolders() As String
Dim FolderCount As Long
Dim FolderIndex As Long


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Select Folder"
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolders = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory).SubFolders

FolderCount = objFolders.Count

If FolderCount > 0 Then
    ReDim arrFolders(1 To FolderCount)
    FolderIndex = 0
    For Each objFolder In objFolders
        FolderIndex = FolderIndex + 1
        arrFolders(FolderIndex) = objFolder.Name
    Next objFolder
    Worksheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(FolderCount).Value = Application.Transpose(arrFolders)
Else
    MsgBox "No folders found!", vbExclamation
End If

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objFolders = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do ***not*** post code in images. Post it as text instead.

Comment: Is there any code that makes new folders? You could launch the sub in your post when this happens. If not, I am not aware of any VBA code that acts as a listener for changes in folders

Comment: Great point Tim, code added as text. 
There isn't any code that makes new folders. But I wonder if theres a macro, button or VBA to run the original vba again but within the format

Comment: What do you mean with "within the format"?

Comment: These days, you don't need VBA for that. You can do that with Power Query (Get and Transform in Excel 2016 or O365), without writing a line of VBA.

Comment: @teylyn Can you reproduce the checkboxes in PQ (or Tables)?

Comment: As @TimStack mentioned, I don't think there is a listener in VBA that would do that but saying that, nothing stopping you from creating a listener to do that. However, VBA seems quiet a heavy language to do that, you could achieve that with scripts

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: I don't think OP is creating the checkboxes automatically (atleast not in the code that is provided). Saying that, there is nothing stopping an automation generation of checkboxes from within VBA everytime a new folder is added (will have to remove them as well if folder is removed).. comes with its own challenges though

Comment: @Zac That would be how I would approach it also (and I have a workbook I use that does just that.  But when teylyn wrote it could be done in PQ, I was wondering if the automatic creation of checkboxes could be done with that tool, also.

Comment: TimStack Within the visual format. 
@teylyn I just came upon VBA when searching for ways to make a list of folders in a folder. I'll check out Power Query and see if that could create what I'm aiming for, thanks ! 
The check boxes are not of great importance, just trying to make overview of tasks quick and easy :)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: not sure if that particular task could be achieved with scripts.. although, just thinking out loud, maybe with a VBA exposed class? not sure

Comment: If you don't need the checkboxes, then just add (or re-write if there will be deletions), the first column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Power Query can read spreadsheet cells as inputs, so, yes, that would be doable. Individual check box controls in  spreadsheet rows is an awful practice, but since each check box value needs to be stored in the grid somewhere, it is possible to feed the values for the check boxes to Power Query for evaluation.

Comment: How come that none of you seasoned participants bothered to edit the question to reveal the screen shot?

Comment: @teylyn I'm pretty new to PQ. Thanks for that information.